# Workaround for edit of type time showing a keyboard without colon

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I need to let the user enter times in format `hh:mm`, but because of the [issue 28132](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=28132) I can't use

```
<EditText ... android:inputType="time">
```

I thought I'd accept any separator, e.g., something like `hh mm` or `hh.mm`, but such characters can't be typed either (logical as they don't belong in time; colon does but is missing from the keyboard). Changing the type to `text` would work, but the text keyboard is not as good for typing.

So I thought about removing the colon just before the edit starts and putting it back when it ends, but I don't know how to recognize these events. `addTextChangedListener` allows to track all fine grained changes, but I don't think it makes sense to change the text *during* the time it gets edited, I'd rather need events like `editStarts` and `editEnds`, corresponding with showing and hiding the keyboard. *Are they such events?*

What workaround for this bug would you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an [InputFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html) for your TextView and validate whether the input is of type Time.

Since TimeKeyListener also implements a InputFilter.

You could probably use

```
 TextView.setInputFilter({new TimeKeyListener()});
```

EDIT:
Or you could even custom time key listener with **.** as a accepted character

```
    edittext.setKeyListener(new TimeKeyListener() {
        public final char[] CHARS = new char[] {
                '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'm', 'p', ':', '.'
        };

        @Override
        protected char[] getAcceptedChars() {
            return CHARS;
        }
    });
```

---

Now it's also easy to replace the alternate separator (dot) by colon like follows:

```
public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
    final CharSequence superSource = super.filter(source, start, end, dest, dstart, dend);
    final CharSequence prefilteredSource = superSource!=null ? superSource : source;
    return prefilteredSource.toString().replace('.', ':');
}
```

Comment: [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/TimeKeyListener.html) is written that *this class is only concerned with hardware keyboards,* but my problem is with poping the wrong software keyboard. So I'm afraid it doesn't apply. I've found also [InputMethod](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethod.html), but it looks really scary.

Comment: it is written that it has no obligation, but usually software iims do use it, did you try it?

Comment: I can currently try it in Eclipse/AVD only and it works there nicely. I added a `filter` method, in case somebody cares.